# how to set VisualStudio auto indent style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, editor

This is VisualStudio default auto indent appearance:

```
XElement sibling = parent.Elements(_element.Name)
    .ElementAt(index);

return _element == sibling ? this  
    : new DynamicXElement(sibling);
```

How to set auto indent to look like it?

```
XElement sibling = parent.Elements(_element.Name)
                         .ElementAt(index);

return _element == sibling ? this  
                           : new DynamicXElement(sibling);
```

using any VisualStudio extension? manual input spaces?

Comment: Tools> Customize > press button keyboard > Text Editor > Basic > Editor > play around with Indent types? I guess you get to have the 4 spaces indent for default, never used another standard anyway

Comment: Are you looking for indentation based upon _what is being indented_?  The options being suggested will change _every indentation_ that occurs.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your Tab key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set these parameters up here : Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Tabs

In your case, just increment the size of indents and that should be good.

Comment: I think OP is looking for something less broad.  It appears that the desired alignment is based upon what is being indented, and that is not supported.